# Error to adding child in NestedScrollView android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I am getting error on Master Detail Flow activity.I created activity in android studio 1.5.1 using android studio GUI. Now i want to add some `textview` in `NestedScrollView` but it will give me error.  My XML Code is below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="app.burhani.gujaratnow.JobListDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/joblist_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World"
        />      
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/joblist_detail_container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />
```

Error is

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.burhani.gujaratnow/app.burhani.gujaratnow.JobListDetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
```

Please help me about this error

Comment: Remove the extra angular bracket at the end in this line - </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>>

Comment: Thank You for your replay. But this is not actually solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved. I just put my layout outside of `NestedScrollView` and give dimen. Here is the solution

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="app.burhani.gujaratnow.JobListDetailActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/joblist_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:fillViewport="true">
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/joblist_detail_container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/joblist_detail_container"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Job Description"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        />
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but your answer is a workaround. Someone get the correct solution?

Answer (score 1):

> You use scrollView according to your error message. And then scrollView should has only one child but your xml says scrollview has one more child.You can move these inside one layout.I hope help you.